# PC suddenly not turning on. Fan is super noisy and fast. Screen not turning on too

Tags: fan

I just left for a few hours and when I get home, my PC is not turning on anymore. It’s a HP Compaq dc7800p running Windows 7.

I’ve never experienced a problem with this PC before because its kinda new. The fan is so noisy and theres a lot of wind coming out of it.

I tried removing and putting back on the RAM. Tried turning it on with one ram removed. Still the same.

Comment: What happens if you take all of the RAM sticks out? Does the behavior change? I've always used this as a test for motherboard failures. If the system beeps without the RAM, and it should, you are likely troubleshooting a power problem. If not, I would think the system board or add-on video card has failed. See Step 2 here to troubleshoot power and address ESD. http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/bph07107#AbT0 - you need to disconnect everything to discharge any static electricity that may be causing the problem.

Comment: @AustinSanderson the light is red. And there is a lot of beeping.. But the same loud as hell fan and the wind is still blowing fast.

Comment: That means there is hope. Try the power reset instructions I linked above and see what happens. After that, you will just start removing/unplugging components until all that is left is the power supply and the motherboard.

Comment: @AustinSanderson ok so i did it and,,, now theres always beeping sound and theres a red flash. im sure its because i unplug and plug thngs in there.. and since i removed and put the ram back in.. now i think the unit hated that and now its worse with the beeping. AND the fan is stil REALLY loud

Comment: Which light is red? Is it blinking? How many beeps are there? Long or short beeps?

Comment: Looking up the model its from 07. Hardly new, and at an age where the PSU could be acting up. I wonder what happens if you try another PSU. Being a small formfactor box, this might end up needing arkward contortions and jerryrigging.

Comment: If you weren't getting beeps before you removed all of the RAM, then you need to ensure that the RAM is properly reseated. You have removed them a few times, so my guess is that one is not properly seated.

Comment: @DavidPostill Actually now, its not beeping and no red light anymore after i switched the ram positions.

Comment: Can you confirm if you followed Step 2 in the link of my first comment? Since you originally were not getting beeps, and when the RAM was out, you did get beeps, I am inclined to think that one of the RAM slots is bad, not the RAM itself. Empty slot 2-->retry booting, move remaining stick to slot 2-->retry booting, put remaining stick in slot 1, empty slot 2-->retry booting. That is how you rule out RAM and RAM slots, unless both sticks are bad, or you have more than 2 slots. Adding comment to other answer as well requesting clarification.If doing that does not change anything, slots are fine.

Comment: @AustinSanderson yes i tried different slots for the two rams.. I dont know why it suddenlt stopped beeping. But im guessing i should just buy a new pc.. and restore the files from my HDD.. Is there still a chance though?

Comment: It's hard to say from our angle. I don't think you have video, so there isn't much to manipulate. I don't think it would hurt you to have a hardware shop check it for you. Hardware diagnostics can be a hands-on process. They probably have a power supply to test with as well. If you think you've discharged all static electricity from the machine, verified power source(s) and ruled out add-on cards and RAM, it's the board or the PSU.

Answer (score 0):

When computers start, they run a [Power-on self-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test), or POST. If the computer finds any errors, it tries to communicate those errors to you by displaying a message on your screen and/or beeping a certain code and/or flashing certain led lights.

In other words: you computer isn't just beeping, it's trying to communicate to you (ok, now give your computer a hug, it needs it :-). For your specific model, you can find the meaning of beeps and flashing leds [here on the HP service page](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01159709&lang=en&cc=us). Checking what's wrong is the first step towards solving the problem.

Comment: Now, theres no more beeping. Just the fan roaring loudly and wind coming out of it is strong. Im considering just buying a new one.. but its just weird for a really good pc to act up all of a sudden. Like ive never had a bad experience since i used this.

Answer (score 0):

On your motherboard, there should be lights that will switch on or off when turning the pc on, locate these lights and they should tell you what issue could be happening.

Most often these lights start with the CPU, RAM, VGA AND BIOS.

If its a CPU issue, you'll have to get a new one.
If its a RAM issue, you might just have to clean the sticks using a brush.
If its a VGA issue, I'm not sure about it.
If its a bios issue, then you will want to reset the CMOS, first find out the type of motherboard your pc is using and then search up where the CMOS is located. There you will have two options, either take out the battery itself for 1 to 2 minutes, or use something conductive like a screwdriver to connect the two pins next to your CMOS battery for 10 ish seconds. I usually take out the battery.

This will cause the bios to reset to default settings, but will keep all your data intact.

Answer (score -1):

Since its relatively new, use your warranty and have it repaired/replaced.

Edit: Since its actually not kinda new, you need to figure out which component is faulty. Try starting it with minimal attached components. Ie, one memory stick, cpu and gfx card. If that doesn't work switch the memory module with another. After that you need to switch out the other components one by one until it starts up.

Alternatively, if the motherboard has a LCD error display you can use the number it gives to see at which startup phase it hangs. Same thing if it does a beep error code.

Comment: its actually not relatively new.. but not old.. but theres no more warranty since i bought this abroad.

Comment: You can skip the graphics card and all the RAM. Without it the PC should still on (though it will throw error codes once it POSTs).

Comment: If he is hearing fans roaring, the PC can turn on. The issue is that it is obviously not getting to POST with all of the components in.  I'll request an edit on the original post because it is unclear what "not turning on anymore means".

Comment: @AustinSanderson i already removed the peripherals connected to it but its still the same.

Comment: Peripherals and internal components are two separate things. Peripherals, by definition, are external. I added a comment on the question above. It is not clear if you tried powering off, unplugging power, and holding down the power button for 15 seconds with everything unplugged. You might also try to flip the power strip on and off, or try another power strip. But I'm leaning towards RAM slot or motherboard (as noted above).