# Changed slots of RAMS and PC is now working, next day, its not working again

Tags: boot, memory, fan, post

This is a continuation of this: [PC suddenly not turning on. Fan is super noisy and fast. Screen not turning on too](https://superuser.com/questions/975468/pc-suddenly-not-turning-on-fan-is-super-noisy-and-fast-screen-not-turning-on-t?noredirect=1#comment1341077_975468)

I already gave up on the pc but yesterday, i decided to check it out again. I tried switching rams. I know i already tried it and it didnt work but last night, when i tried one ram, the screen booted up! then i tried it on a diff slot, then its suddenly not booting.. SO i made a conclusion that there are RAM slots that are faulty..

So i tried different slots.. and finally, IT BOOTED UP just fine!

But when i woke up just now, and turn the unit upright so i can use it, its doing that fan noise all over again.

Whats really going on?

edit: i tried using just one stick again... ITS BOOTING UP!
but im so confused. why is there no pattern of its behavior? I dont get it.

edit 2: ok i left that one stick of ram there and i started windows.. maybe i should just go for 2gb of ram then? but i still dont know what the problem was. is it the ram slots? or is it that one stick of ram?

Comment: First of all, I would RMA your motherboard since it apparently has bad RAM slots. You can test the RAM sticks or slots by running MemTest86. The fan noise can simply come from the fan. Some fans have a much louder dB output than others, and are therefore more noisy. You could replace it for a quieter fan if you wanted to.

Comment: @DrZoo i think the fan is doing that cause its not going on to POST.so its not booting up. well i dont even know who bought this pc. this was just from my brother's office abroad and he gave it to me so we didnt pay anything for this PC

Comment: Do you have a fan controller you could plug it into? It's probably running hooked up to the board in a way which it can't throttle itself. It's probably just running 100% regardless.

Comment: @DrZoo no but im not really gonna focus on the fan since its working now.. and back to normal.. except 1gb less of ram.

Answer (score 0):

If a computer doesn't boot with all the RAM sticks in it, it is usually caused by a broken RAM stick, not by a broken RAM slot.

So I would repeatedly test the RAM slots with a variety a RAM sticks in order to find out which RAM slots are working. Since RAM is cheap, you may be able to **economically** replace the existing 1GB RAM with two sticks of matching 2GB DDR2 RAM, This will give your computer 4GB RAM, allowing you to replace Windows Vista with a modern 64-bit operating system when Vista reaches its end of support on April 11, 2017. By then the computer will be almost ten years old, and you might want to consider installing a Linux distro on it to save the money that you already spent on updating the hardware.

If you want to keep on using the computer, please do something about fixing the noisy fan. I always replace a noisy fan for two reasons.

1. I don't like noisy fans.
2. A noisy fan will typically work at half or less than its normal speed, which can cause the computer to overheat and its hardware components to wear out faster.

Add up the cost of making your computer function normally before you do anything, and then ask yourself if it is really worth investing in refurbishing such an old computer. Because you haven't used the computer for a long time, you don't know how well the computer functions for its age when all of its hardware components are working properly. This represents an element of risk which mitigates against refurbishing the computer. Do you need the computer badly enough that it's worth putting any money into it?

You are a programmer, and I don't recommend that programmers suffer with junk hardware under any conditions, not even using it as a spare machine. As of October 2015, virtual machine software is already so good that I believe that it is possible to replace physical machines with virtual machines in almost all situations that are relevant to programming, physical hardware permitting, and still get close to native performance. This is a bold and controversial statement which I'm sure that many will disagree with or maybe even rail against, but because of it I don't believe that an old business desktop computer that was manufactured circa 2008 is of any value to a programmer.

Comment: And well, *better* machines are suprisingly cheap. And they could run VMs, and use modern hardware that is going to reliably boot up. And you can run VMs on it.